# Cant get rid of a space using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying with google chrome and inspecting elements, but I cant get rid of an annoying space.

I also tried firebug and changing properties in header, headercontainer, etc.

the screenshot of the space I want to remove is here.

I appreciate for your help.

Comment: You should provide the code and/or example and show the specific HTML and CSS where you are trying to find the solution.. we cannot search your complete website.

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome Inspect Element to determine where the spacing is coming from.

Comment: That is so mucky code! Consider cleaning it up using a CSS stylsheet

Comment: Yes i agree @jacktheripper to muddy code need clean your HTML and css. Locaaaaa, i am sorry to say but you have used very bad HTML and CSS styling in your code

Comment: thanks but its not mine, its a template we bought for Magento.  Is there any tool or website I can use that gives me HTML and CSS suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean suggestions? Optimisation tips? For that you should create a stylesheet, upload it to your sever and make a link to it on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're looking for is the `height` of the `<h1>` with class `logo`, currently set to `95px`.

Use [the fine DOM inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Inspector)/Firebug/Chrome's inspect thing/etc next time to find it easily.

Comment: Should probably let OP know that removing that css property will fix the issue.